# XamarinForms FFImageLoading CachedImage issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

I'm getting a `.PNG` image file from an API like so

```
public static async Task<CachedImage> GetImage(string UserID)
{
    var URL = "assumeThisUrlPointsToServer"

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    Stream stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(URL);

    return new CachedImage { Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream) };
}
```

and I am getting a file back and I am displaying it like so

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage HeightRequest="52" Margin="13,0,16,0" Source="{Binding SourceOfReturnedCachedImage}"/>
```

Unfortunately, this is not working (blank). How do I get it to work?

**Additional details :** if I change it to an `Image` instead of `CachedImage`, then it works.
Now the funny thing is that if i specify a `URI` instead of downloading a file, like so,

```
return new CachedImage { Source = ImageSource.FromUri('http://www.website.com/image.png')};
```

Then it (`CachedImage`) works!

Comment: Have you followed all steps mentioned here https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API

Comment: Yup, it wouldn't be working at all if I hadn't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So xamarin provides a simple way to view images, you can just give the url of the image as the source of image/cachedimage so

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage HeightRequest="52" Margin="13,0,16,0" Source="{Binding ImageURL}"/>
```

Where ImageURL is the URL I was downloading the image from

Answer (score 2):

Stream is disposed after every image load, you must modify your code to:

```
public static async Task<CachedImage> GetImage(string UserID)
{
    var URL = "assumeThisUrlPointsToServer"

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    return new CachedImage { Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => {
        return await client.GetStreamAsync(URL);
    })};
}
```